# Displaying SWF file in README.md of Bit Bucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am facing problem to attach Swf file to README.md in Bit bucket ,Can any suggestion how to include swf file README.md.

I tried with some of the suggestion i got from net.

`!filename.mov|height=800,width=600,id=media!`

None of this is working.Can anyone help me out with this issue ?

Comment: You can't, it is not supported: https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/markdowndemo

Comment: Thank You, there is any other way i can show my demo by connecting bit bucket so that viewer can see that video ?